# Как в WPF привязать список из ListView к списку из Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ListView

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="User" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Group" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Group}" />
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Есть ComboBox

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Group}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>
{
  new Group ( "First" ),
  new Group ( "Second" ),
  new Group ("third")
}

Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
{
  new User ( 1, "user1", Groups[0].GroupName ),
  new User ( 2, "user2", Groups[1].GroupName ),
  new User ( 3, "user3", Groups[2].GroupName )
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе в ComboBox определенного Group, в ListView отображался бы User из этой Group.
Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Чего-то у нас здесь последнее время прямо вал вот таких вот `userНомер` созданных под один вопрос. Когда ответ на вопрос получен, то автор тихо сливается и даже спасибо не говорит. Может ну их таких халявщиков, на мороз, т.е. в игнор, как думаете?

Comment: Просьба помощи у более опытного человека, это по вашему халява? Халява в чём? Или возможно я неправильно ( в рамках этого сайта ) задал вопрос? Тогда подскажите, что конкретно не так?

Comment: Просьба помощи у нормального человека, который работает на сайт, т.е. зарабатывает репутацию, пусть даже просто интересными вопросами, это одно. А вот то как вы поступаете: "о, у меня есть вопрос, создам под него очередной аккаунт", а после тихо уходите в небытие. А потом, на очередной вопрос, следующий `userНомер` и так далее. Это бы еще полбеды, а то ведь создают несколько таких юзеров под один и тот же вопрос и спамят ими здесь.

Comment: Все нормальный, хороший вопрос

Comment: хотя не совсем понятно что нужно получить - фильтрацию списка по  выбранному элементу в ComboBox?

Comment: Bulson - я на этом сайте новичок, как и программировании. Хоть и зарегистрировался давно, но вопрос задаю в первый раз. Про репутацию на этом сайт - простите, не в курсе, для меня важно решить задачу, которую я себе поставил. И помощь более опытных программистов для меня бесценна!

Comment: Foggy Finger - да, вы правы именно это и нужно! При выборе группы в combobox, должен выводится список users у которых эта группа.

Comment: я смогу написать пример не раньше вечера, но здесь система уведомлений работает через знак "@". То есть для обращения ко мне нужно использовать @Foggy

Comment: @Foggy Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: Покажите вашу структуру данных. Combobox и ListView привязаны к _одному и тому же_ списку?

Comment: @VladD Нет это два списка, но номер группы у каждого юзера в ListView берется из списка групп в Combobox. Чуть выше прикрепил код.

Comment: @user253039: А у вас группа не знает список своих юзеров?

Comment: @Vlad Нет не знает.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Я дал решение без фильтрации, но с переделкой классов. Надеюсь, это не пересекается с вашим анонсированным решением.

Comment: @VladD если не нужно показывать весь список а только одну из категорий, то предварительная группировка, как мне кажется, будет самым простым и лучшим способом

Comment: В `ComboBox` нет дополнительного пункта который отвечал бы за любую возможную категорию (сброс фильтрации)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, у вас не вполне правильный дизайн. Группа должна знать список пользователей, иначе вам для запроса группы придётся делать JOIN по названию группы. (Отмазки вида «у меня так в базе» не принимаются.)

Итак, меняем структуру классов.

```
class MainVM
{
    public MainVM(IEnumerable<Group> groups) =>
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(groups);
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; }
}

class User
{
    public User(int id, string name, Group group) => (Id, Name, Group) = (id, name, group);
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Group Group { get; }
}

class Group
{
    public Group(string name) => Name = name;
    internal void AddUsers(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        foreach (var u in users) Users.Add(u);
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
}
```

Наш XAML будет при этом предельно простым.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups/Users}"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="User" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Group"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Group.Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Если создать данные вот так:

```
var g1 = new Group("First");
g1.AddUsers(new[] { new User(1, "Витя", g1), new User(2, "Костя", g1) });

var g2 = new Group("Second");
g2.AddUsers(new[] { new User(100, "Иннокентий", g2) });

var g3 = new Group("Third");
g3.AddUsers(new[] { new User(788, "Белка", g3), new User(789, "Стрелка", g3) });

var mainVM = new MainVM( new[] { g1, g2, g3 });
```

и записать `mainVM` в `DataContext` окна, получается такое:

[image: master-detail view, классика из классики]

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, теперь получается я не могу создавать список групп и юзеров через ObservableCollection? Никак не могу понять как теперь создать списки используя ваш пример.

Comment: @user253039: Ну замените `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` на `ObservableCollection<T>` и подправьте конструкторы, чтобы компилировалось.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь! Ваш пример хорош! Буду разбираться, пока слабо понятно, как его применить к своему решению, везде ошибки валяться.

Comment: @user253039 сам пример as is у вас компилируется без ошибок?

Comment: @Foggy Finder не понимаю, что означает as is? Данный пример не могу запустить, т.к. не понимаю как создать теперь списки групп и юзеров, как говорил уже. Но судя по примеру всё должно работать.

Comment: @user253039: Я напишу код для создания дерева объектов чуть позже, когда доберусь до компьютера

Comment: @user253039: Добавил пример с созданием данных вручную, и переделал под `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @VladD Разобрался, вам спасибо за помощь! Печально, что у меня эта задача заняла столько времени, но без StackOverflow видимо было бы ещё больше. )

Comment: @user253039: Очень хорошо, что разобрались! Тяжело в учении — легко в бою!